# Copy-item with multiple filter

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

How can I use copy with multiple filter values?

For example, it works if I specify only 1 value to filter (*.jpg)

```
Copy-Item -Path Y:\TEST -Recurse -Filter *.jpg -Destination D:\Users\MS5253\Desktop\Lots
```

This create me a folder (D:\Users\MS5253\Desktop\Lots\TEST) that contains only jpg files

But I also want to filter xml files, I tried this :

```
Copy-Item -Path Y:\TEST -Recurse -Filter *.jpg,*.xml -Destination D:\Users\MS5253\Desktop\Lots
```

It gives me an error.

and this : `Copy-Item -Path Y:\TEST -Recurse -include "*.jpg","*.xml" -Destination D:\Users\MS5253\Desktop\Lots`

It doesn't work...

Thanks for your help, i'm using Windows 7 with Powershell v4.

Comment: You can't, that parameter does not support an array object. You will have to just use two different commands.

Comment: two different commands does not work, because  if you have nested folder structure, it will throw errors on inability to create a folder or overwrite folders without merging being called with force

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want all the jpg and xml files into one folder, you could use `Get-ChildItem -Include`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Include *.jpg,*.xml -Recurse | ForEach-Object { 
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination D:\Users\MS5253\Desktop\Lots
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to preserve a folder structure, it seems like there's no other way than manual paths management:

```perl
function Copy-Filtered {
    param (
        [string] $Source,
        [string] $Target,
        [string[]] $Filter
    )
    $ResolvedSource = Resolve-Path $Source
    $NormalizedSource = $ResolvedSource.Path.TrimEnd([IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar) + [IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar
    Get-ChildItem $Source -Include $Filter -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
        $RelativeItemSource = $_.FullName.Replace($NormalizedSource, '')
        $ItemTarget = Join-Path $Target $RelativeItemSource
        $ItemTargetDir = Split-Path $ItemTarget
        if (!(Test-Path $ItemTargetDir)) {
            [void](New-Item $ItemTargetDir -Type Directory)
        }
        Copy-Item $_.FullName $ItemTarget
    }
}
```